# Предложите, пожалуйста, пунктуацию (см. контекст)

Tags: пунктуация

Оригинал:

> Я была готова, по русской традиции, что называется: почитать приемной
>   комиссии.

Моё пред(по)ложение:

> Я была готова, что называется по русской традиции, почитать приёмной
>   комиссии.

Обстоятельства: русская актриса экзаменуется перед приёмом в иностранную труппу.

Ну не понимаю я знаков (читай: смысла предложения) оригинала.

А как быть с обособлением "что называется по русской традиции"? Нужна ещё одна запятая? после "называется"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильный вариант следующий: "Я была готова, что называется, по русской традиции, почитать приёмной комиссии."
"Что называется" - вводное словосочетание и выделяется запятыми.

Comment: Та часть, что называется лодыжка. Не всегда вводное!

Comment: Krasus, вводное слово или сочетание может стоять в начале или в конце обособленного члена предложения, тогда пунктуация у/осложняется массой оговорок. См.: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach2

Comment: Вот объяснения, в которых я не уверена - "мои" ли: *Вводные слова и сочетания, стоящие на границе однородных членов или частей сложного предложения и относящиеся к следующему за ними слову или предложению, не отделяются от него запятой: Послышался резкий стук, должно быть сорвалась ставня. А. Чехов, Невеста. (Ср.: Послышался резкий стук. Должно быть, сорвалась ставня.)*

Comment: @shampar, а я нигде не писал, что так всегда. Я отвечал на конкретный вопрос.

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova, в русском языке всегда есть масса оговорок. Повторюсь, что отвечал на конкретный вопрос. В своём ответе я уверен. И кавычки там не нужны, как предложили в другом ответе, и ничего там не дублируется.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, "по русской традиции" дублирует "что называется". По правилам если встречаются два вводных слова или сочетания, запятая между ними ставится: *Чего доброго, пожалуй, и женится, из умиления души...*(Достоевский). Но здесь разный смысл - неодобрение и неуверенность - удачно сочетается.

А в предложенном варианте, мне кажется, одно нужно убрать. Можно убрать "что называется", заменив его кавычками:

Я была готова, по русской традиции, "почитать" приемной комиссии.

Comment: Впрочем, "по русской традиции" - не вводное, а пояснительный оборот, но запятые всё равно нужны, ведь у автора стоят, значит есть необходимость пояснения.